# Parse PHP with Facebook Login

Tags: parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm new to Parse and I'm trying to develop an app that could be accessible by website or a smartphone app.

I searched at Parse tutorials and samples, but I didn't find a sample about how to integrate Parse PHP and Facebook Login. Someone have a sample that could share? Or some tip on how do it works?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained here very well, you also need a single parse command

```
ParseUser::logInWithFacebook($id, $accessToken);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web